# Configuring application in docker container to access other containers

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

How can you configure an app deployed as a docker container to reference components running in other containers? I have a node app that requires postgresql. I have a node config file that contains all the connection information for postgres. In a non-docker deployment, you simply set the required config values (e.g. IP address of the db server etc), but how can this be done in a docker deployment?

I'm using Docker Compose, but can't see how I can find out the necessary IP address of the postgres docker container and then set that value in my node.js config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don need to get the IPs.

You can reach out a container from another container in the same environment (same Docker Compose) by using the "service" name instead of the ip.

Answer (score 0):

**Using domain name**

To connect to your application you don't need the IP, you just need container name.

I will try to explain it on below example.

If you have e.g. docker-compose file like below:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: docker/web
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - dbpostgres 
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html   # I will share my code so I map this path
  dbpostgres: <-- CONTAINER NAME
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - /private/var/lib/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: pguser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pguser
      POSTGRES_DB: pgdb
```

and you want connect to postgres database, all you need to do is use container name instead of the IP address. Here `dbpostgres`

In your config file you should use in this case:

```
parameters:
    database_host: dbpostgres <-- CONTAINER NAME
    database_port: null
    database_name: dbname
    database_user: dbuser
    database_password: pass
```

**Using IP**

If you don't want to use domain name, and want use the IP (I don't know the reason), you can use command:

```
docker inspect project_dbpostgres_1
```

where project_dbpostgres_1 is your container name. You can check container name using `docker ps`.

docker-inspect in section NetworkSettings has key Networks. You should look for IPAddress. There is also Aliases where you can find alias name dbpostgres.

```
 ... "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "7005a7782180462e31e526aa9a5ad89e1943230d57c33930c9f7de26f3917157",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "9000/tcp": null
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/7005a7782180",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Networks": {
            "i2mv3_default": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "31b7550ecd14",
                    "dbpostgres"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "e1a954361a2a325cac15405135d67e716dff4c15ea10d402948bf7dff329c1fa",
                "EndpointID": "9b2ad968df4e55750fe1d1730e33fafa5512012b1669df97d838abf0f25fa506",
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2", <---- YOUR IP
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02"
            }
        }
    }  ...
```